# Configure mex in MATLAB 2018a Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, mex

I have upgrade to MATLAB R2018a on my machine with Ubuntu 16.04.

Before this new install I was able to compile MEX-files on MATLAB R2017a. But now I got an error:

> Error using `mex`
>   `/home/solrad/.matlab/R2018a/mex_C_glnxa64.xml` not found; check that you are in the correct current folder, and check the
>   spelling of '`/home/solrad/.matlab/R2018a/mex_C_glnxa64.xml`'.

I have checked for the file on `/home/solrad/.matlab/R2018a/mex_C_glnxa64.xml` and the file is there.

How can I fix it so the `mex` command works again?

Comment: Did you try `mex -setup`?

Comment: yes this  error is the result of that command. I guess that i have done some symbol links before the upgrade and I don't know what I have done to be able to compile mex files.

Comment: Is `$HOME` the same as `/home/solrad/`? Is `~/.matlab` or `~/.matlab/R2018a` a symbolic link?

Comment: Is $HOME the same as /home/solrad/? 
R: yes
Is ~/.matlab or ~/.matlab/R2018a a symbolic link
R: No

Comment: One thing to try is to delete the `~/.matlab` configuration directory, and run `mex -setup` again (you'll lose any customization you did to MATLAB, so you might want to move it elsewhere temporarily instead of deleting it).

Comment: Hi Cris, Thanks so much. It worked. So now I have to look at files that I had in this directory to see if there is something wrong!!!

Comment: Yes, or you just reconfigure MATLAB from scratch. Depends on how much customization you did. There should be nothing *truly* important in that directory.

Comment: i would recommend if the issue persist and you purchased the license submit a ticket to matlab